# date_part in postgres deliver wrong result when difference is bigger than a year

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp

I have a valid_from and a valid_to columns and want to calculate the number of days between them. I use the following query:

```
select 
   valid_from
   ,valid_to
   ,date_part('day', valid_to::date) - date_part('day',valid_from::date) 
from bp_ips;
```

it delivers me wrong answer:

| valid_from | valid_to | datediff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2008-02-18 | 2020-06-12 | -6.0 |

The answer which I am expecting is shown here [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/132959)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just subtract date columns from each other :

```
select 
   valid_from
   ,valid_to
   , valid_to - valid_from
from bp_ips;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3318e58f1e5104898b9a45db528aa717)*

considering datatype is date or timestamp, subtracting columns in postgresql gives you the difference in days